# unable to display sensor info on j2me

Tags: java, java-me, sensors

I've have written the following code to display the sensors available on the Nokia Asha phones.

```
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Command;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.CommandListener;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Display;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.List;
import javax.microedition.sensor.*;

public class Sensor extends Midlet {

    private Display display;
    private List sensorList;
    private SensorInfo[] sensorinfo;
    private Command exit, list;

    public void SensorBrowser(){

        display = Display.getDisplay(this);
        sensorList = new List("Available Sensors", List.EXCLUSIVE);

        sensorinfo = SensorManager.findSensors(null, null);

        for(int i = 0; i<sensorinfo.length; i++){
                 System.out.println("Sensor #" + (i+1) + ": Description: " +                       sensorinfo[i].getDescription());
        }
        exit = new Command("Exit", Command.EXIT, 1);
        list = new Command("Description", Command.ITEM, 1);
        sensorList.addCommand(list);
        sensorList.addCommand(exit);
        sensorList.setCommandListener((CommandListener) this); 
   }

}
```

When I try to run it on Asha Emulator, all I get is a blank screen.

This may seem like a basic question to many, but I'm new to j2me platform and I could not find any help in this matter.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have done a refactoring and you have changed either the Midlet class name or the constructor function name, but forgot to change the other.

Another problem is your Midlet does not implement the `CommandListener` interface. And I can't see in your code where are you setting the list to the screen. You can do this in the `startApp` method, as in this example:

http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Using_List_in_Java_ME